# Rstudio CentOS 6 unable download 'googleway'

Tags: r, linux, centos, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am new to CentOS 6 and trying to find a way to install the package "googleway"
regardless of what I add. I am currently running Rstudio 3.4.3 so it should be ok on version control.

This is the error I receive:

> > install.packages("googleway") Installing package into ‘/users/myname/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
> >     unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘curl’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_3.2.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 367047 bytes (358 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 358 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googleway_2.6.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3968104 bytes (3.8 MB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 3.8 MB
>
> Using PKG_CFLAGS= Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
>   ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR --------------------------- Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:  *
>   deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: libcurl-devel
>   (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris) If libcurl is
>   already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config is
>   unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD
>   INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------- Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘curl’ had
>   non-zero exit status Warning in install.packages :   installation of
>   package ‘googleway’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpfykCff/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww from your link: `if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

googleway, as an API package seems relevant to that point, IMO

Comment: @AnilRedshift - You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Comment: @jww: This also is for data science development. As a data scientist new to Cent OS I came to this community for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

googleway has a dependency on curl, the installer is unable to install it.

You can try and install curl manually, from the terminal

```
yum install libcurl
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! I don't have sudo access so that was the tough part...